# C# Chain Delegates together with "unknown" signatures

Tags: c#, delegates, method-chaining

I want to do the following:

```
private static Dictionary<string, Delegate> handlers = new Dictionary<string, Delegate>();
private static void RecievedMessage(object sender, RecievedMessageEventArgs e) {
  if(e == null  || e.Message == null) return;

  if(e.Message is RegisterMethodMessage) {
    var registerMethodMsg = (RegisterMethodMessage)e.Message;
    if(handlers.ContainsKey(registerMethodMsg.MethodName)) {
      handlers[registerMethodMsg.MethodName] += registerMethodMsg.Handler; //Error
    } else {
      handlers.Add(registerMethodMsg.MethodName, registerMethodMsg.Handler);
    }
  }
}
```

A delegate added to the chain with the same key in the dictionary will have the same method signature.
If I were to substitute "Delegate" with a specific one like Action, the above code would work.

So my question is:
Is it possible to do the same without the substitution and without a lot of "hacking"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason you can't do this:

```
handlers[registerMethodMsg.MethodName] =
    Delegate.Combine(
        handlers[registerMethodMsg.MethodName],
        registerMethodMsg.Handler);
```

Comment: Thanks for curing my blindness, just what I was looking for.